# Android debug keystore issue with Fastlane and Jenkinc CI

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, fastlane

I have a CI with ephemeral slave dockers, jenkins and fastlane.
In my dockerfile for the slaves, I have the following line:

```
COPY keystore_docker/prod.keystore <path>
COPY keystore_docker/debug.keystore <path>
```

I have defined in jenkins an env variable KEYSTORE_PATH = path

In the Jenkinsfile I have this line:

```
sh "cp  ${env.KEYSTORE_PATH}/*.keystore  app"
```

The apk's for production are correctly signed, but the staging ones, that should use debug.keystore, are not. Strange thing is the signature changes at each build and the certificate Validity as well. This is from the last today build, in fact:

```
        Not Before: Apr 13 17:23:37 2023 GMT
        Not After : Apr  5 17:23:37 2053 GMT
```

Is fastlane generating a debug keystore at each build?
What am I doing wrong?